# Can't get reproducible results on GCP's AI-platform using tensorflow's DNN estimator

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

**The Problem**

I am unable to get reproducible results on GCP's AI-platform using TensorFlow 1.14. This makes hyper-parameter tuning difficult because I'm unsure if the changes in performance are due to the hyper-parameters themselves or due to randomness.

The model is a simple out of the box DNN estimator.

**What I've Tried**

- Setting a random seed in the run configuration
- Setting a global graph seed

In my `task.py` file I have the following:

```
    tf.set_random_seed(42)

    ...

    run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(tf_random_seed=42)

    estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
            feature_columns=feature_columns,
            n_classes=len(target_list),
            optimizer=tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=args.learning_rate),
            batch_norm=True,
            model_dir=model_dir,
            config=run_config)
     ...
```

Is there something else that needs to be done in order to get reproducible results?

Comment: This might be a shot in the dark but you could also try fixing the numpy seed.

Comment: are you training on a single machine or distributed? Distributed will be hard to get repeatable results with, because of randomness in how workers finish

Comment: @Lak I am training on distributed machines. So is there no way to get repeatable results in distributed training? This might explain why the results are repeatable locally but not on ai-platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using parameter server strategy for distributed training, you won't get repeatability. 
If repeatability is important to you, use mirrored strategy (or multiworker mirrored strategy). By design, there is no way to get repeatability with parameter server -- parameter server is faster precisely because it avoids tail latency by not waiting for straggling workers.